# angular 2 children modules inheriting parent services

Tags: angular

In following the guide on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards  we are breaking up different routes into nice bite size modules.. But it seems like a bit of an overhead in code now if for each module i need to include all the rel. services, providers and pipes...

Does ang2 pass down the imports to the children modules?

eg:
...

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DndModule.forRoot(),
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        StoreModule.provideStore(
            StoreLoader.reducers(),
            StoreLoader.initialState()
        ),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentStore({
            monitor: useLogMonitor({
                visible: BootstrapDataService.reduxStoreDebug(),
                position: 'right'
            }),
        }),
        StoreLogMonitorModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(
                http,
                window.crowdRoute + 'assets/i18n',
                '.json'
            ),
            deps: [Http]
        })
    ],
    declarations: [
        //Pipes
        SummaryPipe,
        DateFormatPipe,
        MomentDatePipe,
        TimeAgoPipe,
        SanitizeHtml,
        SafePipe,
        ValuesPipe,
        DisplayNamePipe,
        UserHasPermissionPipe,
        UserHasRolePipe
    ],
    bootstrap: [CrowdComponent],
    providers: [
        BootstrapDataService,
        CommentService,
        Helpers,
        ImageService,
        ProjectService,
        SuggestionService,
        AuthService,
        AuthResolver,
        {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
            useValue: window.crowdRoute
        },
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) => new CrowdHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, null),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
        },
        {
            provide: BrowserXhr,
            useClass: CrowdBrowserXHR
        }
    ]
})
export class CrowdModule {}
```

Right now the app does not have split up modules for each area.. so right now all the providers etc are passed through the rest of the app.

But... from the ang2 plunker https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HeroesModule,
    LoginRoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DialogService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The main `app.module.ts` includes modules which themselves include their own routing etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any way of passing imports from a parent module to child modules.

Although Angular 2 does have a way to share common imports between multiple modules and reduce the boilerplate using a SharedModule. See:
https://angular.io/styleguide#04-10

Something like:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DndModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.provideStore(
        StoreLoader.reducers(),
        StoreLoader.initialState()
    ),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentStore({
        monitor: useLogMonitor({
            visible: BootstrapDataService.reduxStoreDebug(),
            position: 'right'
        }),
    }),
    SummaryPipe,
    DateFormatPipe,
    MomentDatePipe,
    TimeAgoPipe,
    SanitizeHtml,
    SafePipe,
    ValuesPipe,
    DisplayNamePipe,
    UserHasPermissionPipe,
    UserHasRolePipe
    StoreLogMonitorModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(
            http,
            window.crowdRoute + 'assets/i18n',
            '.json'
        ),
        deps: [Http]
    })]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
           BootstrapDataService,
           CommentService,
           Helpers,
           ImageService,
           ProjectService,
           SuggestionService,
           AuthService,
           AuthResolver,
           {
               provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
               useValue: window.crowdRoute
           },
           {
           provide: Http,
               useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) => new CrowdHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, null),
               deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
           },
           {
               provide: BrowserXhr,
               useClass: CrowdBrowserXHR
           }
          ]]
       };
  }
}
```

And then in your child and main modules all you need to import is that SharedModule and specific(not common) imports for your modules.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        , SharedModule]
      ... Other code
    })
export class MyModule { }
```

You can see a good implementation of this in the angular seed project: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/src/client/app/shared/shared.module.ts